# Como puedo buscar en columnas relacionadas DataTables?

Tags: laravel, ajax, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: Esta es mi DataTable]

La cosa es que, los campos ***Nro. Ficha*** y ***Encargado*** son columnas que no pertenecen a la tabla ***"trabajos"*** de la BD, por lo que son campos relacionados y extraidos desde las otras tablas (obviamente relacionadas), mi duda es, como puedo hacer que el **search** del DataTable funcione sobre estos campos? pues cuando quiero buscar un trabajo por el nombre de un encargado, simplemente me muestra el mensaje de DataTable empty

[image: DataTable empty]

Mi controller para llamar a los datos es el siguiente:

```
public function trabajoData()
{
    $consultas = Trabajo::all();

    return Datatables()
            ->eloquent(Trabajo::query())
            ->addColumn('nro_ficha', function($consultas){
                return $consultas->mantenimientos->nro_ficha;
            })
            ->addColumn('placa', function($consultas){
                return $consultas->mantenimientos->vehiculos->placa;
            })
            ->addColumn('empleados', function($consultas){
                return $consultas->users->name.' '.$consultas->users->apellido_pater;
            })
            ->addColumn('btn', 'trabajos.actions')
            ->rawColumns(['btn'])
            ->make(true);
}
```

Luego en mi vista:

```
var table = $("#trabajos-table").DataTable({
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                ajax: '{!! route('datatables.trabajos') !!}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'fake_id', name: 'fake_id' },
                    { data: 'nro_ficha', name: 'nro_ficha' },
                    { data: 'placa', name: 'placa' },
                    { data: 'manobra', name: 'manobra' },
                    { data: 'tipo', name: 'tipo' },
                    { data: 'estado', name: 'estado' },
                    { data: 'empleados', name: 'empleados'  },
                    { data: 'btn', name: 'btn',orderable:false,serachable:false,sClass:'text-center' }
                ]
            });
```

Muchas gracias por su tiempo de antemano

Comment: Deberías de leer la documentación de laravel en apartado de scopes en los modelod. Todas las consultas las puedes hacer desde un modelo y obtener la demás data atravez de las relaciones. Si compartes tu diagrama entidad relación podría explicarte más a detalle.

Answer (score 1):

Una rápida respuesta es hacer un scope search en tu modelo trabajo.

```
// suponiendo que este es tu modelo trabajo

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trabajo extends Model
{

  public function scopeSearch($query, $search){
    $query->
    join('tabla_b', 'tablab.user_id', 'trabajo.id')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($search){
            $query->where('trabajo.phone', 'LIKE', "%$search%");
            $query->orWhere('trabajo.name', 'like' , "%$search%");
            $query->orWhere('trabajo.lastname', 'like', "%$search%");
            $query->orWhere('tablab.json', 'like', "%$search%");
            $query->orWhere(\DB::raw("CONCAT(name, ' ',lastname)"),'like', "%$search%");
        });

        return $query;
    }
}
```

como lo mandarias a llamar

```
Trabajo::search($search);
```

El resultado de la consulta sera la instancia de tu modelo. Si no tienes las relaciones no agregara la data de las relaciones.